# Azure Function fails with "Could not load assembly ..." How to get more info?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

When I deploy and run my Azure Function I get the error

> ```
> 2018-06-27T13:34:40.566 [Error] A ScriptHost error has occurred
>
> 2018-06-27T13:34:40.566 [Error] Could not load assembly 'DataContracts'.
>
> 2018-06-27T13:34:39.316 [Info] Function started (Id=1473028c-b249-415f-8755-0fdbe2b1f3dc)
> ```

in Streaming Logs, without any more detail about why the assembly can't load. I cannot reproduce locally; I created a console project to host my function and it does not get this error when I run it.

Any suggestions about how I can investigate this issue?

Comment: How are you referencing this assembly in your project?

Comment: @CamBruce by project reference

Comment: How is this deployed? Are you using the inline C# code editor within the function app?

Comment: @CamBruce No, building locally and then deploying.

Comment: Is this `DataContracts` a self-defined class library?

Answer (score 0):

Here are three ways you could view azure functions error logs:

1.In Portal: Select function and go to Monitor tab. Select Invocation and on the right-head to see the logs.

2.In KUDU: You get to that by navigating to `https://myfunctionapp.scm.azurewebsites.net`. Then you need to select `Tools | WebJobs` dashboard and then choose `Functions`.

3.Table Storage: If you have the Azure SDK installed, then in Visual Studio you can browse to this in the `Cloud Explorer window`.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](http://markheath.net/post/three-ways-view-error-logs-azure-functions).

Also, as you could not load assembly but work well in local, select the resource assembly files, and in the Properties pane, set Copy to Output Directory to “**Copy always**”.